# Can't get tensorflow dataset to be accepted by the model.fit function. Some problem with dimensionality

Tags: tensorflow-datasets, bmp, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to decode bitmaps using the line of code below

```
img = tf.image.decode_bmp(img, channels=3)
```

create a tf.dataset of image/label pairs out of it using the `.map` function

```
test_labeled_ds = test_list_ds.map(process_path)
```

and feed it into `model.fit`

```
model.fit(test_labeled_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_labeled_ds)
```

using the model architecture below

```
i = Input(shape=(40,40,3))
x = Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=2, activation='relu') (i)
x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=2, activation='relu') (x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=2, activation='relu') (x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(5, activation ='softmax')(x)

model = Model(i, x)
```

But when I run `model.fit` I get the following error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (40, 40, 3)

I've tried changing the input shape to things such as `i = Input(shape=(1,40,40,3))`

But then I get a different error in the model:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_3 is incompatible with the layer:
>   expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 1, 40, 40,
>   3]

So it would appear that the tf.dataset is actually 4dims and it's correct that my input should be specified with 3 dims as per (40, 40, 3)

So why doesn't this work?
Do I have to do something to the dataset object before I feed it to the model?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone who may encounter this in the future, I've managed to find the problem. The clue is in the error message. I was confused as my model clearly stated that the input would be (40, 40, 3) and yet the error said that it expected 4 dims and got an input (40, 40, 3).

But that's the answer right there. The models 'fit' function expects a 4D input. I was trying to feed in the whole dataset object (which is a 3D object) and it was expecting 4D.

It expects 4D because the other dimension is the batch size, which is why when you batch up the dataset and feed that in, it suddenly works. Batching up the data, add that extra dimension.